# How to disable any grouping in NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

NSNumberFormatter has a method

```
- (void)setGroupingSize:(NSUInteger)numDigits
```

when I would provide a 0 here, is that disabling any grouping for sure? I really don't want any grouping to happen, no matter if the user has a locale of Takawaka or US. I need a safe way to get rid of any grouping here. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your looking for:

```
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look at NSNumberFormatter's documentation. You'll find you want to use -setHasThousandSeparators: ...